# Vue, Jest, jQuery - Testing jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, jestjs

I have this test.

```
    test('Can registerFormListener', () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, "registerFormListener");
        wrapper.vm.registerFormListener();
        expect(spy).toBeCalled();
    });
```

This is spying on this function.

```
registerFormListener: function () {
oiService.initFormValidation(selection);
}
```

Which calls this validation function.

```
static initFormValidation(selection: string, () => void) {
            $(selector).validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: false,
                        email: true
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "Please enter an email"
                    },
                },
                submitHandler: function() {
                    onSubmit != null ? onSubmit() : null;
                }
            });
}
```

However, Jest isn't picking up on any of the jQuery in this function. I get the error `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function`.

I have jQuery installed in my package.json, but to get Jest to pick it up I had to add a setup-jest.js file and tell it to pick up all the global variables we use.

Will I also have to add this and every other jQuery function into this setup-jest file to get it to pick up the validate function? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the Jest stuff, but `$('.foo').validate()` is not a native jQuery method. It requires the [jQuery validation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-validation) (or perhaps some other plugin with a `validate()` method, but that's the one I've seen most often).

Have you installed `jquery-validation` in your project?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I'm pretty unfamiliar with jQuery. I've installed `jquery-validation` but Jest is still having issues detecting validate.

Answer (score 0):

To use jQuery validation you import it in your test

```
import validate from 'jquery-validation';

test('validation', function () {
    expect(validate).toBeDefined();
});
```

You'll also want jQuery in your setup-jest.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```